# While loop to check for valid user input?

Tags: python, while-loop, user-input

Python newbie here so sorry for what I'm sure is a stupid question, but I can't seem to solve the following challenge in a tutorial that is asking me to use a while loop to check for valid user input.

(using Python2.7)

Here's my code, but it's not working properly:

```
choice = raw_input('Enjoying the course? (y/n)')
student_surveyPromptOn = True
while student_surveyPromptOn:
    if choice != raw_input('Enjoying the course? (y/n)'):
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
    else:
        student_surveyPromptOn = False
```

The above prints out to the console:

```
Enjoying the course? (y/n) y
Enjoying the course? (y/n) n
Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: 
Enjoying the course? (y/n) x
Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: 
Enjoying the course? (y/n)
```

Which obviously isn't correct — the loop should end when the user enters either 'y' or 'n' but I'm not sure how to do this. What am I doing wrong here?

Note: the challenge requires me to use both the `!=` operator and the `loop_condition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A shorter solution

```
while raw_input("Enjoying the course? (y/n) ") not in ('y', 'n'):
    print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again:")
```

### What your code is doing wrong

With regard to your code, you can add some print as follow:

```
choice = raw_input("Enjoying the course? (y/n) ")
print("choice = " + choice)
student_surveyPromptOn = True
while student_surveyPromptOn:
    input = raw_input("Enjoying the course? (y/n) ")
    print("input = " + input)
    if choice != input:
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again:")
    else:
        student_surveyPromptOn = False
```

The above prints out:

```
Enjoying the course? (y/n) y
choice = y
Enjoying the course? (y/n) n
choice = y
input = n
Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again:
Enjoying the course? (y/n) x
choice = y
input = x
Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again:
Enjoying the course? (y/n)
```

As you can see, there is a first step in your code where the question appears and your answer initializes the value of `choice`. This is what you are doing wrong.

### A solution with `!=` and `loop_condition`

If you have to use both the `!=` operator and the `loop_condition` then you should code:

```
student_surveyPromptOn = True
while student_surveyPromptOn:
    choice = raw_input("Enjoying the course? (y/n) ")
    if choice != 'y' and choice != 'n':
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again:")
    else:
        student_surveyPromptOn = False
```

However, it seems to me that both Cyber's solution and my shorter solution  are more elegant (i.e. more pythonic).

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried the solution with the != and loop_condition but when user enters either 'y' or 'n', it asks the question again. How can I get the loop to quit after someone enters either 'y' or 'n' the first time the question is asked?

Comment: You're welcome. Which code are you talking about? My solution with `!=` and `loop_condition` does not ask the question again after someone enters either `'y'` or `'n'`. I suppose you have tried something different. If so, please could you edit your question to add this piece of code?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the condition

```
while choice not in ('y', 'n'):
    choice = raw_input('Enjoying the course? (y/n)')
    if not choice:
        print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

The very simple solution for this is to initialize some variable at the before  the loop kicks in:

```
choice=''

#This means that choice is False now

while not choice:
    choice=input("Enjoying the course? (y/n)")
        if choice in ("yn")
            #any set of instructions
        else:
            print("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
            choice=""
```

What this while conditional statement means is that as long as *choice* variable is false--doesn't have any value means *choice*=''-- ,then proceeds #with the loop
If the *choice* have any value then proceed with enters the loop body and check 
the value for specific input, if the input doesn't fulfill the required value
then reset the *choice* variable to False value again to continue prompts user 
until a correct input is supplied